# Visual Studio 2012 keyboard shortcuts within ASP file's VBscript not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts, comments

I'm currently working on an ASP Classic site (ugh, I know...) and so I'm editing an .asp file within Visual Studio 2012. I have the keyboard shortcut for commenting a block of code in the text editor (Edit.CommentSelection) set to "Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C". I **can** use the keyboard shortcut to comment blocks of code in the HTML part of the file, but it **doesn't** work when trying to comment blocks of code within VBSCRIPT portions (anything within the <%...%> tags). Is there a way to remedy this, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this yet, but I _have_ found an interesting workaround. You hold down Alt and left-click and drag the single space that precedes each line of code (or at least the left-most line). Then press the `'` (apostrophe) which is the commenting character for VBscript. It's easiest when the block of code that you want commented is indented at least one space, but it's still possible even when it's left-aligned. You still press Alt and left-click just to the left of the first line and drag down, you just won't drag horizontally at all.